# Create git repo with jgit and put a file into it

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have the following code to generate a new git repo and put a .gitignore into it:

```java
  Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir(gitProjectDir.toFile())
        .setWorkTree(gitProjectDir.toFile())
        .build();
    repo.create();

    // Add a file from the resources to the repository
    try (Git git = new Git(repo))
    {
      Files.copy(Thread.currentThread()
          .getContextClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("gitignore.txt"), gitProjectDir.resolve(".gitignore"),
          StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

      try
      {
        git.add()
            .addFilepattern(".gitignore")
            .call();

        git.commit()
            .setAuthor("CMBUILD", "cmbuild@continentale.de")
            .setMessage(jiraTicket + ": Hinzufügen von .gitignore")
            .call();
      }
      catch (GitAPIException e)
      {
        throw new IOException(
            "Could not create the commit", e);
      }
    }
```

While this seems to work (if you clone the resulting repo, you get one commit that contains the `.gitignore` file), it also seems to be not quite correct because the git repo (not the clone!) that I generate looks like this:

```bash
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        28.08.2023     11:22                branches
d-----        28.08.2023     11:22                hooks
d-----        28.08.2023     11:22                logs
d-----        28.08.2023     11:22                objects
d-----        28.08.2023     11:22                refs
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22            105 .git
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22           4505 .gitignore
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22             36 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22            214 config
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22             23 HEAD
-a----        28.08.2023     11:22            112 index
```

So the `.gitignore` just lies within the repository files.

How can I adjust the code to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `setGitDir` incorrectly. From an archived version of the API I could find;

> Set the Git directory storing the repository metadata.

In other words, you're telling jgit not to use the `.git` directory but instead use the project dir itself.